# deleting extra "users" made by IIS

Tags: iis

I installed IIS10 to my computer (Windows 10) and it made a lot of user accounts under my `C:\Users\` folder.

These don't show up like user accounts in anything else, though. I can't remove them using the `Settings -> Accounts` user interface for example.

If I'm done with IIS, or am not using the Application Pools associated with them, is it safe to delete them? And if so, how can I do that?

Comment: If you've uninstalled IIS, you should be safe to delete them.

Comment: Can I just delete the folders?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "Computer", and select "Properties", then click on "Advanced system settings" (alternative way - just run "sysdm.cpl").
Go to tab "Advanced" and click button "Setting" in "User profiles" group.
Unused profiles that created by IIS pool will have name "Account Unknown", select it and click "Delete" button.

Visit [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241994/delete-windows-user-created-by-iis-applicationpoolidentity#:~:text=Go%20to%20tab%20%22Advanced%22%20and,and%20click%20%22Delete%22%20button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241994/delete-windows-user-created-by-iis-applicationpoolidentity#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20tab%20%22Advanced%22%20and,and%20click%20%22Delete%22%20button).